# Is it necessary to upload subca to browsers trusted certs or is rootca sufficient?

Tags: web-browser

We have set up a subca to sign certs and we have deployed the rootca cert to a browser but we still get security warnings unless we upload the subca cert to the browser.

My understanding is trusting the rootca cert should be sufficient. Is my understanding wrong or does it look like there is something wrong with the cert chain? Inspection of the certificates and chain shows the chain is correct and we haven't got mixed up in all the testing but I could be wrong :)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to have the root-CA in the browser. Your TLS server needs to provide all the intermediate certificates in the TLS handshake though, so that the client has all the necessary certificates to build the trust chain from server certificate to the trusted root CA. It is a common error to forget to configure the server accordingly, i.e. often only the leaf certificate is sent but the chain certificates are missing, are in the wrong order or are the wrong ones.